# File archiving software

Tags: windows, email, archiving

We use KERIO mail server, as a secondary e-mail server. KERIO stores the e-mails in directorys*.eml.

For example:

User1 mail box stored something like this:

```
  2009\msg\*.eml
  2010
  Calendar
  Drafts
  ...
  INBOX\msg\*.eml
  etc
```

We are looking for a free / open source archiving software to export/archive the hole directory structure with eml files too.

For example I give a date to the software and this will export (and delete the original files) the directories till this date to an other directory.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting yet simple question.  I checked a few freeware utilities, and a couple low-end backup packages.  None provided the ability to select the working set with a date filter.

Comment: and i need a sw. which has the ability to delete the successfully backed up files...